# query sql returning custom value

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns (containing  Integer values that assume only values from 0 to 10). I want extract, with a single query, a table with 1 column. This column must assume a value based on the following logic:

1. If one of these three columns has value 0 ----> the value of column of table generated by query must be 0 too.
2. If none of the last three columns has value 0 ----> the value of column must assume the value 1.

Comment: Actually if the fields are always in the 1..10 range -- hence never 0 -- a query that matches your request would be `SELECT 1 FROM tbl;` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `CASE` construct or `IF` function:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (t.field1 = 0 OR t.field2 = 0 OR t.field3 = 0) THEN 0
       ELSE 1 END AS value
FROM t;
```

In this specific case you might also use the fact that any member being zero will zero the product:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (t.field1*t.field2*t.field3 = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS value
FROM t;
```

Or

```
SELECT IF((t.field1*t.field2*t.field3)=0, 0, 1) AS value FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple case statement.  Assuming there are no NULL values, try this:

```
select (case when col1 = 0 or col2 = 0 or col3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  
    CASE
    WHEN column1 = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN column2 = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN column3 = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END
FROM urtable
```